# Entity Framework Relation with ApplicationUser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hello I'm having trouble establishing a relationship with an ApplicationUser class, you can't browse! Can anyone help?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Book> Book{ get; set; }
}

public class Book
{

    public string UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Get the model in the Controller

// GET: Books
public async Task Index()
{

```
    var list = from s in _context.Books select s;

    ApplicationUser ApplicationUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

        if (!await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(ApplicationUser , "Admin"))
        {
            list = list.Where(s => s.ApplicationUser == ApplicationUser);
        }

        list = list.Where(s => s.State== BookUtils.States.ACTIVE);

    return View(await list.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
}
```

When I try to browse the model Book.cshtml @item.ApplicationUser = NULL ????

Can anyone help with this navigation?

Comment: You haven't shown us how you are getting the model in your controller action method?

Comment: I added the information

Comment: OK, you are not getting the user in your query. Also, the linq you have here is redundant. You can just to `return View(await _context.Books.Include(b => b.ApplicationUser).ToListAsync());`

Comment: I did it this way because I have to apply filters, I already updated above. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Do I have to do the Include? Shouldn't it be automatic?

Comment: Because my Book has a relationship with another class, I wanted to do

Book.ApplicationUser.OtherClass.name

and not that I wanted to worry about including the dependencies!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      ApplicationUser ApplicationUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

        if (!await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(ApplicationUser , "Admin"))
        {
                  var list = await _context.Books 
                        .Where( b=>  b.UserId==ApplicationUser.UserId
                              && b.State== BookUtils.States.ACTIVE )
                       .AsNoTracking()
                       .ToListAsync();
              return View(list);
       }  
return ...else
```

Comment: Hi thanks. In the model above there is some way to browse the models without including dependencies in the query select?

For example I intended to Book.ApplicationUser.OtherClass.OtherRelatedClass.name

Comment: It depends. Could you post  the full ApplicationUser  and what you have tried already?

Comment: Book book = await _context.Book .FindAsync(id); book .ApplicationUser.Email  .In this example I don't want to worry about including the ApplicationUser in the select. I wanted the entity framework to be about dependencies. But if it doesn't include it gives Book.ApplicationUser = NULL. Isn't it supposed to be able to navigate through attributes using primary / foreign keys?

Comment: In this case if you want some more info in a book instance you will have to include some stuff. But if you use await _context.Book .Select({}).FirstOrDefaultAsync(...);  you probably don't need. I need to see the result object.